# Set data using a setting method in the constructor in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I have a class that has like 11 variable that need to be set up using the input provided by users. This class has the following constructor and method:

```
public class Sample {

int id;
Date date; 
String location;
int sampleNum;
(...)
String[] keywords; 

public Sample()
{
    keywords = new String[5];
    setData();
} 

public void setData()
{
location = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("");
sampleNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(""));
....
....
....
....
}
```

This is because i have another class with a method like this:

```
 public class SamplesList {

Sample sample;
boolean inUse;
SamplesList next; //next element in SamplesList 
SamplesList prev; //previous element in SamplesList 

public SamplesList (){
    inUse = false;
    next = null;
    prev = null;
}

public void setSamples()
{
int sampleNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(""));
for (int i = 1; i <= sampleNum; i++)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data #"+i);
    this.add(new Sample()); 
     //assuming SamplesList has a method add() that works exactly like an ArrayList.
  }
}
```

I need to create i Samples that need to be set up by input and added to a List. But when i call everything in the main.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    SamplesList sL = new SamplesList();
    sL.setSamples();
}
```

sampleList has added the right amount of element in the desired list but with every variable as if they have not been set up.

Can you recommend me something? I know having a method in a constructor is a bad idea D:

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question about an hour ago?  Why are you re-posting?

Comment: I deleted the old one like 7min after I posted it because the explanation I gave was incorrect.

Comment: it is good design to ensure that a class has *as few dependencies as possible*. In your posted code your class is dependent on the Gui for setting its values. The class should not have to know about the gui at all. Instead, pass the values as arguments to the constructor or a class method that sets its member variables.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend getting all the variables in an array of strings inside of setSamples() then calling a constructor with that array as a parameter. That way you can set all the values of variables within the sample class within the constructor.